# How do you extend the list of timezones Python is aware of?

Tags: python, time, timezone

How do I make more timezones understandable to Python?

```
>>> import time
>>> date='Wed Dec 31 20:37:36 EST 1969'
>>> pattern='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
>>> seconds_from_eopch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date, date_pattern)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Wed Dec 31 20:37:36 EST 1969' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

What I have been able to find out is that EST is being rejected; the only time zones understood by my computer are those listed in tome.tzname:

```
>>> time.tzname
('PST', 'PDT')
```

I naively tried just adding EST to the list, but it did not help.

How do I "legitimately" add EST?

Answer (score 3):

`time.tzname` always contains two values. You should install the [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) package for general timezone support in Python (as timezone information changes regularly it's not part of the standard library but requires a separate download / installation).

You can then use any of the elements in `pytz.all_timezones` as timezones - which can be constructed using `pytz.timezone(name_of_timezone)`.

Comment: I installed pytz, but it made no difference: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The standard library isn't very good here, I tend to use the dateutil package which can parse whatever string you give it.